# How secure is a private key?

Tags: security, private-key, cryptography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to brute force bitcoin address creation in order to steal money?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22/is-it-possible-to-brute-force-bitcoin-address-creation-in-order-to-steal-money)

I've tried [brainwallet.org](http://brainwallet.org) and now I wonder, what happens if someone starts to generate a lot of private keys and add them to his wallet (or MtGox account)? That person will eventually get somebody else's private key and be able to use his/her Bitcoins. Am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming there are 1 million addresses with a non-zero balance, and you can import 1 million keys per second, you will on average get a hit after approximately 3.5 billion billion times the age of the universe.

Comment: Hi Tomas and welcome! See the link now added to the OP.

Comment: I get a similar number to Pieter: age_of_universe = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25 * 14.6e9; keys_per_second = funded_addresses = 1e6; keys = 2**160; keys / keys_per_second / funded_addresses / age_of_universe -> 3.1720679605540234e+18    I expect he used something other than 14.6 billion years for the age of the universe to get his slightly higher answer.

Comment: @ChrisMoore Thanks. Really good explanation. I just though that if BTC is the future money, billons of active addresses will be around but that is still really improbable.

Comment: Even billions of active addresses is not at all a problem.