# What's the most efficient method to try and guess a wallet's private key?

Tags: private-key

I have a Bitcoin address that I want to guess its private key.

What's the most efficient way to do it?

I don't mean "use a trillion servers" but "use this program this way".

Note that it has to run on windows.

I know that it's pretty much impossible for a PC to guess a private key (more possibilities than atoms in the universe and all that) but still, it could be the very first key I try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22/5406

Answer (score 2):

There is no known way to 'efficiently' guess at the private key for a specific address. The best method is simply brute force guess-and-check, and given the massive address-space, the chance of guessing correctly is essentially zero.

Comment: @nickpapoutsis: No one has created a program or dictionary for this - mainly because it would be futile. You may as well just enumerate all the keys in sequential order then generate HD addresses (with some gap limit, say 100) and check each address. You'll need your own copy of the blockchain for efficiency of checking. Indexed by address obviously. See [Large Bitcoin Collider](https://lbc.cryptoguru.org/about) - though I don't think that really does exactly what you are asking.